# Serenity BDD Ensure class not available from Screenplay Assertions

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I have a Java Maven project using Serenity BDD (serenity-bdd) combined with Selenium to run automated tests.
The pom.xml includes the serenity-bdd dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-ensure -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
    <artifactId>serenity-ensure</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I import the **Ensure** class is not available. Other classes sush **Actor** are available:

```
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor;
import net.serenitybdd.screenplay.ensure.Ensure;
```

```
WebElementFacade lableObj = Find_ClientPage_Element(ObjectName);
String actText = lableObj.getText();
Actor aster = Actor.named("QA");
aster.attemptsTo(Ensure.that(actText).isEqualToIgnoringCase(expText));
```

I have updated the Maven repo. I've also followed this documentation:
https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/serenity-screenplay-ensure.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I updated to version 3.2.0, it was fixed when I went back to version 2.3.5

```html
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>serenity-ensure</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31839505)

Answer (score 0):

The Serenity BDD author, John Ferguson Smart, proposed here to do a 'mvn verify' oustide the IDE(blaming the IDE for that glitch). He talks about it here: https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/1235